# Set the date for rows with common value in a column based on a 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

df1

```
S.No   T.No    Amt    Date
1      34       10    20-6-2021
2      34       30    21-6-2021
3      34       20    22-6-2021
4      21       50    23-6-2021
```

Objective: In cases of same T.No the date for all of those should be the one associated with the highest amt.

Output:

```
S.No   T.No    Amt    Date
1      34       10    21-6-2021
2      34       30    21-6-2021
3      34       20    21-6-2021
4      21       50    23-6-2021
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
>>> df['Date'] = df.loc[df.groupby('T.No')['Amt'].transform('idxmax'), 'Date'].reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
   S.No  T.No  Amt       Date
0     1    34   10  21-6-2021
1     2    34   30  21-6-2021
2     3    34   20  21-6-2021
3     4    21   50  23-6-2021
>>>
```

First solution, use `groupby` and `transform` with `idxmax` and `loc` with `reset_index`.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your help, your first solution did the trick.

Comment: @MDJ Your welcome :) remember what to do when someone answers :) remember to click the check mark :P

Comment: Second solution was really bad, good you remove it.

Comment: @jezrael yeah, that's true

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices, here `Date`s, because converted by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to new column:

```
df['Date'] = df.set_index('Date').groupby('T.No')['Amt'].transform('idxmax').to_numpy()
print (df)
   S.No  T.No  Amt       Date
0     1    34   10  21-6-2021
1     2    34   30  21-6-2021
2     3    34   20  21-6-2021
3     4    21   50  23-6-2021
```

Or instead `transform` is used [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Date'] = df['T.No'].map(df.set_index('Date').groupby('T.No')['Amt'].idxmax())
```